# Загадка о воробье и лошади

Tags: общие-вопросы, терминология

Загадка: *воробей может съесть горсть зерна, а лошадь не может. Почему?*

Правильный ответ: воробьи не едят лошадей.
Однако многие дают ответ в отношении лошади: мол, она не может съесть горсть зерна потому-то...
Вопрос: как называется это явление с точки зрения русского языка (когда как бы два смысла у вопроса)?

Comment: В качестве оффтопа: в английском языке такие загадки называются умным словом неизвестного происхождения - conundrum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Семантическая омонимия.*** 
Термин не очень употребилетен, но вполне понятный лингвистам.
У термина есть синомимы ("геторосемия", например), но они еще менее употребительны.

Вопрос - и ответ, естественно,  никаким образом с загадками вообще не связан.  такое встречается сплошь и рядом, вспомните хотя бы объемнейший цикл анекдотов про Штирлица. Но коль вы уж вы загадки как пример привели, я продолжу.
Указанная семантическая омонимия может базироваться:

a) исключительно на омонимах или омофонах одного слова. ***"Где начало того конца, которым кончается начало"?*** - здесь обыгрывается разные значения слова "конец"

б) на омофонии разных слов - ***Отчего утка плавает? (От берега)***. Этот случай близок    к ***игре слов или каламбурам*** (в узком смысле).

в) на семантико-синтаксической неодназначности отношений во фразе ***Сидело пять уток, охотник убил двух. Сколько осталось? - (две и остались, остальные улетели)***.

г) подвид предыдущего - на грамматической омонимии словоформ. Это наш случай. "Лошадь" в винительном и именительном падежах звучит одинаково - на этом и построен эффект.

Думаю, для первого ознакомления достаточно.